# How to connect Tablet and PC without Internet connection

Tags: websocket, webrtc, wifi, hotspot

I have two applications that communicate between themselves with websocket and webRTC
Those applications meant to work offline.
The communication works offline while thous applications run on the same computer.
I know that Thous protocols can work between two devices connected by wifi between them.

My plan is to run a server on a PC and connect to it with Tablet through wifi.

So my question is. With an offline computer. Can I create a local wifi network and connect a tablet to this network to enable websocket and webRtc communications?

Comment: It might help solicit better responses if you identified the computer and tablet make/model and OS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should have no problem, even better you won't need a turn/stun server because your pc tablet won't be hidden behind NAT